# how to make customise MPMediaPickerController view iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to make some changes on color on MPMediaPickerController view.

```
 MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES; // this is the default
[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
[mediaPicker release];
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the  barStyle of  the MPMediaPickerController i think you can not customize all the MPMediaPickerController   It's possible (likely) that the media picker doesn't have a navigation toolbar at the point in time that you are attempting to set the toolbar style. Have you checked to see that mediaPicker.navigationController has a value ?

I'd recommend embedding the media picker controller into your own view hierarchy (the docs for MPMediaPickerController say it's possible), and then you will have complete control over the navigation bar from your own view controller.

```
// create media picker controller
mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

// set properties
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Choose your song:";

// get the media picker's view and set its frame
UIView *pickerView = mediaPicker.view;
pickerView.frame = myViewController.view.frame;

// add the media picker view to the view hierarchy
[myViewController.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

You Need Go through [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html/)

Comment: but can you help me for change the navigation bar color change in mediapicker view?